# Code breaks - It's something because of the threads

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio

#### Here's the code,

- I either want to wait for executing GetData() - this gives error saying  " The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

  ```
      BorrowedList.ItemsSource = new List(Of book) (await BookService.GetBooksBorrowed(UID))
  ```

Tried making this a sync function - still doesn't work

- or have a delay of 200ms.

  ```
   Public Async Sub GetData(uid As String)
  dim data as ArrayList = await MemberService.GetMember(UID)
  BorrowedList.ItemsSource = new List(Of book) (await BookService.GetBooksBorrowed(UID))
  LblUID.Content = UID
  LblName.Content = data(0) + "" + data(1)
  LblPhone.Content = data(2)
  LblDepartment.Content = data(3)
  LblSemester.Content = data(4)
  _dashBoard.MemberPopup.Content = Me
  _dashBoard.MemberPopupDialog.IsOpen = True
  End Sub
  ```

This is the call

```
 Private Async Sub QrScanned(jsonString As String)
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.ScannerBeep, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    Try
        If jsonString.Contains("UID") Then
            if Await CheckBookInList 'Checks and returns book if found
                GetData("MEM-0001")
                await Task.Delay(200)
                _sendImage.Start()
            ElseIf await BookService.Borrowed("BOOK-2","MEM-0001") 
                    GetData("MEM-0001")
                await task.Delay(200)
                _sendImage.Start()
            Else 
                MsgBox("Failed to Update database")
            End If
        else
            MsgBox("Please scan a book to add or return")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox(ex.ToString())
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to look into `Dispatcher.Invoke`, it will be what you need. The error is specific, dont access a thread you do not own by trying to update...

Comment: The code forgets to await GetData()

Comment: How do i fix it @HansPassant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was poped as I was trying to UI therad with other theard; which is not possible as WPF runs on STA [Singe Thread Apartment].
To fix the issue I had to Call the UI thread from the other thread by calling Dispatcher.invoke.

The  corrected code would be:

```
   Public Async Sub GetData(uid As String)
    dim data as ArrayList = await MemberService.GetMember(UID)
    Dim x = new List(Of book) (await BookService.GetBooksBorrowed(UID))
    Me.Dispatcher.invoke(Sub()
             BorrowedList.ItemSource = x
             LblUID.Content = UID
             LblName.Content = data(0) + "" + data(1)
             LblPhone.Content = data(2)
             LblDepartment.Content = data(3)
             LblSemester.Content = data(4)
             _dashBoard.MemberPopup.Content = Me
             _dashBoard.MemberPopupDialog.IsOpen = True
         End Sub)  
End Sub
```